# Content Security Policy Violation on File Preview

Tags: html, google-chrome, content-security-policy

This is quite odd, and I've checked around and attempted many things to no avail.

I have a simple file upload, it displays the image prior to uploading it. This works fine in my local development environment, and it also works fine on the staging server.

On the production server, it doesn't work. This is what is showing in my console:

> refused to load the image 'blob:https://example.com/a7ced718-483b-4bc2-9db0-f012c8c6af5a' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:

However, I have no CSP defined, and it works fine on an exact replica server utilized for staging to test for bugs.

Furthermore, I've tried to add a CSP in the meta tag at the head of the document, but it does not solve the problem either. This is the CSP I attempted to implement:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; img-src https://*; child-src 'none';">
```

Can anyone shed some light into why this may not be working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the response headers the server sends (using browser devtools or `curl` or whatever).

The production server must be sending a `Content-Security-Policy` response header.

If so, the reason your `meta` element has no effect is, the browser uses the most-restrictive CSP policy, wherever it’s specified—and the `Content-Security-Policy` header your production server is sending is more restrictive than the one you’re specifying with the `meta` element.

See the details on multiple polices at https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#multiple-policies and the details on  the `meta` element at https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#meta-element —

> A policy specified via a `meta` element will be enforced along
> with any other policies active for the protected resource, regardless
> of where they’re specified. The general impact of enforcing multiple
> policies is described in §8.1 The effect of multiple policies.
>
> #### 8.1. The effect of multiple policies
>
> The impact is that adding additional policies to the list of policies
> to enforce **can only further restrict** the capabilities of the protected resource.

So it seems that the `Content-Security-Policy` header your production server is sending has `img-src 'self' data:` but in order for your image URL to be allowed and to avoid the error you’re seeing, the `Content-Security-Policy` header your production server is sending needs to at least also include `blob:` in its source list: `img-src 'self' data: blob:`.